# Google cloud endpoints API key is not verified

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, api-key

I'm now developing REST API with Cloud endpoints and App engine.
I will like to implement api key authentication but it does not work.

Looks good without query params of 'key=${API KEY}'.

```
# curl -X POST https://hogehoge.com/test -d '{"key":"value"}'
{
 "code": 16,
 "message": "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}
```

But any key can be granted to access to the backend.

```
# curl -X POST https://hogehoge.com/test?key=aaa -d '{"key":"value"}'
POST is sended.
```

Of course, API key generated via API management will work.

```
# curl -X POST https://hogehoge.com/test?key=${realkey} -d '{"key":"value"}'
POST is sended.
```

Cloud endpoint file definition is

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: "xxxxxxxxx"
  description: "xxxxxxxxx"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "hogehoge.com"
schemes:
  - "https"
security: []
paths:
  "/test":
    post:
      description: "test"
      operationId: "test"
      security:
        - api_key: []
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/testRequest'
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Success"
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/testResponse'
definitions:
  testRequest:
    type: object
    required:
      - data
    properties:
      data:
        type: object
        required:
          - key
        properties:
          token:
            type: string
            example: value
            maxLength: 20
  testResponse:
    type: string

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

What I expect is only key generated via API management will be granted to access.
Let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste your endpoint file definition?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I pasted it.

Comment: Where do you redirect your query?

Comment: I changed host from real one to dummy host 'hogehoge.com'. Basically my query is not  redirected.

Comment: Can you tell me if @jose-v answer works? If not, I have another idea about the issue.

Comment: @nkm I have followed all the steps mentioned in the answer section too. But, I am still able to query, i.e., apikey authentication is not taking place. Please guide me how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the Service Control API might not be enabled on your project.

In order to check that, you can run

```
gcloud services list --enabled --project your-gcloud-project-name
```

If servicecontrol.googleapis.com is not listed in the result of the previous command, you should run

```
gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com --project your-gcloud-project-name
```

Furthermore, you could check that you have all the required services for Endpoints enabled. You can see how to do this in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-standard#checking_required_services)

Comment: Sorry for late. As you said, it's the cause that servicecontrol was not enabled.
Now it's working fine.
`
# gcloud services list --enabled  | grep servicecontrol.googleapis.com
# gcloud services enable servicecontrol.googleapis.com
Operation "operations/acf.xxxxx" finished successfully.
# curl -X POST https://hogehoge.com/test?key=xxx -d '{"key":"value"}'
{
 "code": 3,
 "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}
`

Comment: I am glad I could help! If the answer was useful for you, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that the community sees it solved your issue. Thanks!